# Создание прыжка как в игре google динозавр в unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

В общем нужно сделать прыжок как в игре google динозавр в unity. При быстром нажатии на кнопку пробел, происходит маленький прыжок, а при долгом нажатии высокий прыжок. Еще, нужно сделать динамический прыжок зависящий от долготы нажатия кнопки, при этом, даже если кнопка была нажата на милесекунду, происходил прыжок на определенную высоту, и если кнопка прыжка зажата слишком долго, то этот прыжок будет усиливаться. Можете пожалуйста привести пример кода если не трудно. Спасибо

Comment: милесекунда -- произведение мили на секунду? :)

Answer (score 1):

Ничего сложного. Нужно запустить корутину, которая будет отсчитывать время, когда клавиша будет нажата.

У меня в зависимости от количества секунд увеличивается сила прыжка.

*только здесь не пробел, а левая кнопка мыши у меня, но, думаю, несложно будет заменить*

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _rb;
    private Coroutine _timer;
    private float _seconds;
    public int forceUp = 100, forceForward = 50;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

private void Update()

    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            _timer = StartCoroutine(CountOfSeconds());

        }


            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            StopCoroutine(_timer);
            _rb.AddForce(new Vector2(forceForward * seconds, forceUp * seconds));
            _seconds = 0;

        }
    
    }

 private IEnumerator CountOfSeconds()
    {
        _seconds++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я уже сделал такой прыжок который я хотел, но проблема в том что нужно каждую секунду проверять касается ли персонаж земли, метод OnCollisionStay2D не подходит, так как вызывается только один раз, есть ли способ проверить коолизию между обектами без метода OnCollisionStay2D?

Comment: А через OnCollisionEnter2D и OnCollisionExit2D пробовал?

Comment: Они работают примерно одинаково